# Constantly updating cookie causes browser crash

Tags: javascript, cookies, greasemonkey

**PROBLEM BACKGROUND:**

I usually leave my browser parked on my fantasy baseball live scoring page overnight. The next day, the browser is always sluggish and frequently crashes.

After some investigation, I'm convinced it's caused by a cookie being updated every 1 second by the site. If I have 5 tabs open on the sites' domain (which I frequently do), it updates the cookie 5 times per second.

**DEBUGGING:**

I use Firefox 4.0 with firebug and firecookie.

The session cookie is called "*fsr.a*" and contains a *nix timestamp. I believe it's called "foresee-trigger" and it's some kind of adware.

You can see it in action here (no need to log in): http://www.cbssports.com/

The cookie seems to be set by this file: http://sports.cbsimg.net/js/phase2-min-v0047.js

**THE FIX:**

I've tried Adblocking it, but that broke the site. I tried writing a Greasemonkey script to counter it, but I'm not good enough with JS yet. I obviously can't block all cookies on the domain.

Just looking for ideas or maybe a pointer in the right direction with a Greasemonkey script.

**EDIT:**

I wonder if I can just change the timer variable with Greasemonkey to update the cookie less frequently?

For reference, I believe this is the code responsible for the "*fsr.a*" cookie:

```
var FSR = {
    version: "5.3.0",
    date: "11/11/2009",
    enabled: true,
    files: "http://images.cbssports.com/script/foresee/",
    id: "7alXWMyc064b1ROgR/DloA==",
    sites: [{
        path: /\w+-?\w+\.(com|org|edu|gov|net)/
    }, {
        path: ".",
        domain: "default"
    }]
};

function fsr$setAlive() {
    var a = new Date().getTime();
    document.cookie = "fsr.a=" + a + ";path=/" + ((FSR.site.domain) ? ";domain=" + FSR.site.domain + ";" : ";")
}(function () {
    if (window != window.top) {
        return
    }
    function g(k) {
        if (typeof k == "object") {
            var l = k.constructor.toString().match(/array/i);
            return (l != null)
        }
        return false
    }
    var e = FSR.sites;
    for (var h = 0, a = e.length; h < a; h++) {
        var c;
        if (!g(e[h].path)) {
            e[h].path = [e[h].path]
        }
        for (var j = 0, b = e[h].path.length; j < b; j++) {
            if (c = document.location.href.match(e[h].path[j])) {
                FSR.siteid = h;
                FSR.site = FSR.sites[FSR.siteid];
                if (!FSR.site.domain) {
                    FSR.site.domain = c[0]
                } else {
                    if (FSR.site.domain == "default") {
                        FSR.site.domain = false
                    }
                }
                if (!FSR.site.name) {
                    FSR.site.name = c[0]
                }
                var d = ["files", "js_files", "image_files", "html_files"];
                for (var h = 0, f = d.length; h < f; h++) {
                    if (FSR.site[d[h]]) {
                        FSR[d[h]] = FSR.site[d[h]]
                    }
                }
                break
            }
        }
        if (c) {
            break
        }
    }
    if (!window["fsr$timer"]) {
        fsr$setAlive();
        window["fsr$timer"] = setInterval(fsr$setAlive, 1000)
    }
})();
```

Alternate paste: http://pastebin.com/YrHFCZn1

Comment: Do they have a helper function to set the cookie? You could shadow it, and pass the cookies besides that one to the original.

Comment: I don't think so. Seems like they just dumped a bunch JS into the one file (phase2-min-v0047.js) and load it normally.

Comment: I just want to come back here (months later) and make sure everyone knows that Firebug is the main reason for the Firefox (4.0, 4.0.1) crashing/slowdowns. Searching the net, this is no secret.

Comment: FYI: ForeSee appears to be a survey & "session replay" tool and there's some details about what the cookie(s) are used for here: http://demo.foreseeresults.com/_code/docs/ForeSee_Trigger_Code_Implementation_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to be registered and logged in for that site to set that cookie.  I won't do that, so I can't test the fix.

BUT, looking at that JS, one or more of the following should work from Greasemonkey:

1. `clearInterval (unsafeWindow["fsr$timer"]);   unsafeWindow["fsr$timer"] = null;`
2. `unsafeWindow["fsr$setAlive"] = function () {}`

---

Worse comes to worst:

1. Copy that JS file to your PC.
2. Edit it, to kill that timer.
3. Use adblock to block just the original JS file.
4. Use Greasemonkey to apply your modified JS.

Comment: Hmm, I logged out of the site and tested the cookie was still being set and updated. Weird. Thanks for the code above! I'll give 'er a try tomorrow and cross my fingers.

Comment: The first command, by itself, works: `clearInterval (unsafeWindow["fsr$timer"]);` ... neither of the other two commands work by themselves. Many thanks, I never would have figured it out on my own.

Comment: You're welcome.  Does killing the cookie fix the bloat/instability like you had postulated?

Comment: It helped, but it's not fixed. I've seriously tried almost everything I can think of. From FF 2.0 thru FF 4.0. Extensions and plugins enabled and disabled. I'm beginning to think it's either bad JavaScript on cbssports.com or Firefox is just inherently prone to sluggishness and crashing. EDIT: I will report back if I can find a fix.

Comment: Try disabling or restricting flash with [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/), Adblock, etc.   I personally also use the [RequestPolicy add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/) to great effect.   Just beware that this add-on requires a lot of training.

Comment: I will give those a try and report back. I'm determined to resolve this and keep using FF. Last night I disabled all plugins except Flash and disabled all addons except Adblock and Greasemonkey. The result: this morning everything seems GREAT! Will keep testing. ;)